# copy a decode ffmepg avframe return -22

Tags: c++, ffmpeg

I have a avframe after sws_scale, and I need a new frame to backup this frame.
I use av_frame_clone() to clone a new frame, but return NULL.
I use av_frame_alloc() and av_frame_copy(), av_frame_copy() return -22.
And when I debug the code, step by step in av_frame_clone, the same error at av_frame_copy(), also return -22.
so, how to copy/clone this frame.

the code like this

```
if ( packet && packet->stream_index == this->ctl->index )
    {
        if ( avcodec_send_packet(this->ctl->context, packet) == 0 )
        {
            while (1)
            {
                int ret = avcodec_receive_frame(this->ctl->context, this->ctl->frame);

                if ( ret == AVERROR(EAGAIN) || ret == AVERROR_EOF )
                {
                    break;
                }

                if ( ret == 0 )
                {
                    sws_scale(this->ctl->convertCtx, (const unsigned char* const*)this->ctl->frame->data, this->ctl->frame->linesize, 0, this->ctl->context->height, this->ctl->frameYUV->data, this->ctl->frameYUV->linesize);

                    AVFrame* nf = av_frame_alloc();
                    int re1 = av_frame_copy_props(nf, this->ctl->frameYUV);
                    int re2 = av_frame_copy(nf, this->ctl->frameYUV);

                    qDebug("result %d == %d ", re1, re2);

                    emit decodeVideoFrame(this->ctl->frameYUV);

                    usleep(21750);

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

the results of copy_props and copy are 0 and -22.
I tried av_frame_clone() instead av_frame_copy(), but the frame is NULL.

Comment: Check if the source frame has all the properties set correctly.

Comment: no, never set properties. But the av_frame_clone also return NULL. I debug into the source code, this function set properties, but also return -22 at av_frame_copy

Comment: For example `av_frame_copy` which can be called by `av_frame_clone` checks the format and width/height for video or sample/channel count for audio, so it could fail at that point if they were not set on the source before the clone: https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/frame_8c_source.html#l00678

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: ok, I upload the part of copy frame. I used the av_frame_clone() instead of av_frame_copy(), return NULL.